# Ошибка js: Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, plotly, qwebengineview

Мне нужно отобразить **`plotly`** график в окне *PyQt5*. 
Тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522103/how-to-have-plotly-graph-as-pyqt5-widget на такой вопрос уже ответили. 
Но после запуска скрипта оттуда выходит ошибка:

> js: Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему.

```
#pip install PyQtWebEngine 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import plotly.express as px


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot', self)
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.browser)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_graph)
        self.resize(500,400)

    def show_graph(self):
        df = px.data.tips()
        fig = px.box(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker")
        fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="exclusive") # or "inclusive", or "linear" by default
        self.browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs="cdn"))
        #print(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs="cdn"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже как-то по другому ругалось.

Обновил **`plotly`**:

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade plotly
```

и все ok.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import plotly.express as px


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot', self)
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.browser)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_graph)
        self.resize(500,400)

    def show_graph(self):
        df = px.data.tips()
        fig = px.box(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker")
        
        fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="exclusive")               # or "inclusive", or "linear" by default
#        fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="inclusive")        
        
        self.browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs="cdn"))
        #print(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs="cdn"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробовал обновить, но все равно не работает. Так же попробовал запустить на виндовс 10 (у меня 7)  там все прекрасно работает, значит это, наверно, какие то внутренние проблемы моего компа.

Comment: @Salavat у меня Windows 7  и все работает.